# Magento Admin Strip of Post Data

Tags: adminform, post-data

all,
Got problem on catalog product page of Magento admin. I have a customer tab called DC, which sets design and colour for a product. A product has multiple designs and one design has multiple colours. After I clicked "save" or "save and continue edit" button at catalog product page of admin, it will pass a form of data which passes 9000 colours by attribute called `product[colour][design_id]=colour_id` with below architecture(I got this record from Ajax call at chrome's network):

```
form_key:R9ciMhP8JKHhEF32
product[status]:2
product[description]:
assigned[designs]:xxxxxxx
product[colour][1][]:1
...
product[colour][9000][]:9000
page:1
limit:20
form_key:R9ciMhP8JKHhEF32
```

We got all attributes.However, we didn't get all records of `product[colour][design_id]`. It only got 830 colours at the back end. I also debugged at Zend's HTTPS getPost function, I still only got 830 colour. Here is the backend data I got:

```
array(
product[status]:2
product[description]:
assigned[designs]:xxxxxxx
product[colour][1][]:1
...
product[colour][830][]:830
page:1
limit:20
)
```

Anyone have idea that why that happened?
Thank you very much.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars whats the limit of this php.ini setting? Most likely this is your culprit but is there for a reason. Consider batching in chunks vs the entire 9000 to avoid such.

Comment: Has increased post_max_size to double size. No change on the receiving data. Check PHP log, found a warning that : PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0. Not sure will that effects my receiving data. Will do a test on that. Thank you very much.